# How to show address suggested by google map in js model popup when i want to edit address text box field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, html

Please help me to resolve the below issue :

i want to show google map suggestion address when i press key on address field, but it is not showing in js edit model popup,

[image: This is My Page, look at the address field in edit popup]
 Link : http://api.ranbasera.in/api/manageflat/admin/serviceList.php

```
username/password : admin/mflat

but the same code i used on simple create services page, there it works fine on the below link :

http://api.ranbasera.in/api/manageflat/admin/createService.php
```

[image: This is the exact what i want to do, Please check the Address field when i click on it and press any key then google suggestion address dropdown will show. This taks i want to do in the edit popup]

```
___________________________________________________

my code for Edit popup: 

 <div class="modal hide fade" id="serviceModaledit" style ="top: 45%;">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="formReset('propNeedModaledit')">x</button>
                <h3>Edit Property - <span id='name'></span></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" style ="max-height: 500px;">
                <div class="box-content">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" action = "#"  id="serviceModaledit1" method="POST">
                        <input id="hidden" name="hidden" type="hidden" value="">
                        <input id="sd" name="sd" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $sd ?>">
                        <input id="ed" name="ed" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $ed ?>">
                        <fieldset>
<div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label">Address</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <input class="input-xlarge focused" id="autocomplete" name="autocomplete" type="text" onFocus="geolocate()" value=""></input>
                                </div>
                            </div>
</fieldset>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="formReset('propNeedModaledit')">Cancel</a>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="edit" value="edit" onclick="formSubimitter('serviceModaledit1', 'serviceModaledit')">Save Changes</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div><!--/.fluid-container-->
___________________________________________________________
```

js code :

```
 <script>
// This example displays an address form, using the autocomplete feature
// of the Google Places API to help users fill in the information.

var placeSearch, autocomplete;
var componentForm = {
  street_number: 'short_name',
  route: 'long_name',
  locality: 'long_name',
  administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
  country: 'long_name',
  postal_code: 'short_name'
};

function initAutocomplete() {
  // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
  // location types.
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
      {types: ['geocode']});

  // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
  // fields in the form.
  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
}

// [START region_fillform]
function fillInAddress() {
  // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
  console.log (place);

  for (var component in componentForm) {
    document.getElementById(component).value = '';
    document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
  }
  document.getElementById('save').disabled = false;
  // Get each component of the address from the place details
  // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
    if (componentForm[addressType]) {
      var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
      document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
    }
  }
  if (place.geometry.location.H && place.geometry.location.L)
  {
      document.getElementById("H").value = place.geometry.location.H;
      document.getElementById("L").value = place.geometry.location.L;
      document.getElementById("addr").value = place.formatted_address;
  }

}
// [END region_fillform]

// [START region_geolocation]
        // Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
        // as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
function geolocate() {
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                    var geolocation = {
                        lat: position.coords.latitude,
                        lng: position.coords.longitude
                    };
                    var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
                        center: geolocation,
                        radius: position.coords.accuracy
                    });
                    autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
                });
            }
        }
        // [END region_geolocation]
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDgOH4myK4L5186othubJ2jxoDO3OCww-o&signed_in=true&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
        async defer></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just look for the wrapper that have the google maps' results and set higher z-index in order to make it appear over the modal.

Usually google maps inserts a `<div class='pac-container'></div>` in the body.

In a my solution i moved that element in wrapper that contains the input in order to make the dropdown results an element of the modal

`$(".pac-container").insertAfter($('#input'));`

Comment: 6 years later... lol